# Creating form for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need some help setting the up the form and the *create* action for a controller with multiple models. Currently, the form will submit, but nothing is processed, or recorded, and no error is shown.

The idea is this: A user can sign up and manage his account. He can then create a "care" account, which basically only require a name to get started, and doesn't need other validations since the child account won't be using email/password to login. If the child account later want access, the parent account can set the email/password for it then, and it will become a full account. This parent account, manager, can also invite another account, maybe a spouse, to act as another manager for this child account.

Thanks in advance for your help

*Account Model*

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :email, presence: true, 
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX},
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                length:     { maximum: 32 },
                unless: :child?

has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "manager_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :cares, through: :relationships, source: :care
has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "care_id", class_name: "Relationship", dependent: :destroy
has_many :managers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :manager
...
def child?
  false
end

class CareUser < Account

 def child?
   true
 end
end
```

*Relationship Model*

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :care_id, :manager_id, :type

 belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Account"
 belongs_to :care, class_name: "Account"

 validates :manager_id, presence: true
 validates :care_id, presence: true
end
```

*Cares Controller*

```
class CaresController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @cares = current_user.cares
  end

  def new
    @user = CareUser.new
    @care = Relationship.new
  end

  def create
    @user = CareUser.new(params[:first_name])
    logger.info @user.inspect
    if @user.save(false)
      @care = current_user.relationships.build(current_user.id, @user.id, params[:relation])
      if @care.save
        flash[:success] = "New care has been successfully added."
      else
        flash[:error] = "Failed"
        render action: new
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = "Failed adding user"
      render action: new
    end

  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

When `@user = CareUser.new` I get `uninitialized constant CaresController::CareUser`, the subclass ... but no error is displayed if it set it to `@user = Account.new`, the parent class.

*The submit form, cares/new.html.erb*

Not sure what the correct way to set up the form, but since submitting to two models, I used `form_tag` instead of `form_for`. Currently I can't seem to get the form to submit correctly, not sure if the problem is in the form, the model or the controller.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <h1>New care</h1>
    <%=  form_tag("/cares", method: :post) do %>
        <% if @user.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <div class="alert alert-error">
                The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "errors") %>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                    <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <% if @care.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <div class="alert alert-error">
                The form contains <%= pluralize(@care.errors.count, "errors") %>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <% @care.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                    <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>

        <%= label_tag(:first_name, "First name:") %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:first_name) %>

        <%= label_tag(:relation, "Relationship") %>
        <%= select_tag(:relation, options_for_select([ ["Son", "1"], ["Daughter", "2"], ["Father", "3"], ["Mother", "4"], ["Grandson", "5"], ["Granddaughter", "6"], ["Grandfather", "7"], ["Grandmother", "8"] ])) %>


        <br>
        <%= submit_tag("Create care account") %>


    <% end %>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: which file are you using to define `CareUser`?

Comment: you should use `app/models/care_user.rb`

Comment: the most common way is to use `accept_nested_attributes`

Comment: @juanpastas CareUser is defined inside the account.rb file, since it's simply a subclass of Account. Do I need to place it inside another file?

Comment: @apneadiving I've looked into `accepts_nested_attributes`, but not sure if it's the right use for this case.

Comment: I don't remember well, but I think you need to define CareUser in a separate file.

Comment: Also you have to use `accepts_nested_attributes` as mentioned above, since you want to save `user` and a `care` "inside" that user. hehehe, also your controller will be simplified when you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`